# mysql query exact match on json field not working

Tags: mysql, json

table looks like this:

```
my_table
id (int)   create_time (timestamp)   meta_data (json)
1          2019-01-20 18:35:42        {"my property": "123"}
2          2019-01-20 19:35:42        {"more data": "456"}
```

I've tried querying with:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE meta_data = '{"my property": "123"}';

SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE meta_data = '\{\"my property\"\: \"123\"\}';
```

And it doesn't work, how can I query an exact match on a json field string?

I noticed this DOES work...

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE meta_data LIKE '\{\"my property\"\: \"123\"\}';
```

Do I need to use `LIKE`? Why `=` not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know the JSON field is a special field type that is designed to let you easily query specific properties, but I wanted to be able to just check against the full JSON easily. And clearly the JSON field has some parameters that cause the `=` not to work as I expected.

This is the solution I figured out, cast `JSON` as `CHAR`:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE CAST(meta_data as CHAR) = '{"my property": "123"}';
```

Another option:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE meta_data = CAST('{"my property": "123"}' AS JSON);
```

> You can also obtain JSON values by casting values of other types to the JSON type using CAST(value AS JSON);" 
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-quote

Comment: While this might answer your immediate question, it is not optimal, at least from the point of view that it won't scale well as the complexity of your JSON string grows.

Comment: thank you so much for this answer. I agree it's not ideal, but it's getting me over the issue right now.  Why do you think you second option is better?   @TimBiegeleisen is there a better option available? I think I may need to raise this in the MySQL forums if there's not.

Comment: @AndrewBrown I don't know why I thought the second option was better, probably purely a preference thing of whether you should cast the original data, or the data you are comparing it with. And whether you should cast the original to a char/string, or cast the comparison data to JSON (the data type of the original)

Comment: The 2nd option allows the DB to perform the match in a way that is independant of the key order. The first option would fail if the there was more than 1 key in the object and the string representation had them in a different order.

Answer (score 2):

Use `JSON_CONTAINS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(meta_data, '"123"', '.$"my property"');
```

[image]

### Demo

Notes:

- Since the target value to match for the key `my property` is a literal string, we need to also search for the double quotes.
- To escape the key `my property` in the JSON path, we can escape that using double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try (modify according to the right name of the property and datatype. If String use "123".

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(meta_data, "$.`my property`")= 123
```

Or may be

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(meta_data, "$.my property")= 123
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare a JSON column to a JSON value, then use [JSON_OBJECT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) to create the value.

Demo:

```
create table t (id int primary key, data json);

insert into t values (1, json_object('my property', '123'));
insert into t values (2, json_object('more_data', 456));

select * from t where data = json_object('more_data', 456);
+----+--------------------+
| id | data               |
+----+--------------------+
|  2 | {"more_data": 456} |
+----+--------------------+
```